# Which of the following maps from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are diffeomorphisms

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my assignment in smooth manifolds and I am struck on it.

> Which of the following maps from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism?

(a)$f(t) =t^5$ (b) $f(t)=e^t$ (c) any bijective immersion (d) any bijective submersion.

I have proved (a) , (b) to be not diffeo.

Definition  in my notes: Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. A map $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called diffeo. onto its image f(U) if (i) f in $C^1$ (ii)f is bijective. (iii) f(U) is open and $f^{-1}$ is $C^{1}$.

Answer is that (c) and (d) are diffeo.

The problem in both (c) and (d) i am having is that I am unable to prove that  $f^{-1}$ in c and d is continuous. f is differentiable ( using definition of immersion and submersion) => f is continuous. It is given bijective.$f^{-1}$ is continuous will be sufficient to prove that $f(U)$ is open.

Can you please help.

Comment: "diffeomorphism _onto its image_" should make "$f$ is bijective" into "$f$ is injective". Every function is trivially surjective onto its image, but not necessarily onto its codomain.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ being continuous is generally true for bijective continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. A proof of this can be found in most introductory analysis textbooks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905015/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-and-bijective-is-f-1-mathbbr#:~:text=The%20answer%20is%20yes.,also%20strictly%20monotone%20on%20R.

Comment: Question solved